# Adding a photo as a JFrame background

Tags: java, swing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myForm.setSize(500, 400);
    myForm.setLocation(0, 0);
    myForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);              
    myForm.setVisible(true);
    // try {
        // myForm.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Heshamm\\Desktop\\light.jpg"))) ) );
         //} catch (IOException e1) {
         //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error !!!", null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
         //}
   draw.mai(myForm, jp1, button, tf[0], tf[1], tf[2], tf[3]);
```

And this is the mai() function in another class

```
        public void mai(JFrame myForm, JPanel jp1, JButton[] button, JTextField tf1, JTextField tf2, JTextField tf3, JTextField tf4)
    {

        myForm.getContentPane().removeAll();
        jp1.removeAll();
        jp1.add(button[0]);
        jp1.add(button[1]);
        jp1.add(button[2]);
        jp1.add(button[3]);
        jp1.add(button[9]);
        jp1.add(button[4]);
        tf1.setText("");
        tf2.setText("");
        tf3.setText("");
        tf4.setText("");
        Hotel.update();
    }
```

Okay so, I have this code, and I wanted the img to be displayed as a background behind the buttons, but when I uncomment try and whats inside it, the frame only displays the background without the buttons, how can I fix it?

And here's the update() function.

```
    public static void update()
{
    cbChoice="";
    myForm.add(jp1);
    myForm.repaint();
    myForm.revalidate();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an image to JLabel and strech the JLabel like background.

There is a simple example :

```
   ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
   . . .
   JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Image and Text", icon, JLabel.CENTER);
   label1.setSize(frame width, frame height);
```

Comment: I get this error
"The method createImageIcon(String) is undefined for the type Hotel"

Comment: Please be sure from your (pic) file path.

Comment: ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Heshamm\\Desktop\\light.jpg");

Same path as the code I posted in the original post, and the other can sucessfully find the pic.

Comment: Ok, try this way if you want : JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("image path")))).